# Set local day time into a variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a diagram with week_day and it has 2 atributes:
Day and Daycode

Then I used to Oracle Live SQL to create the table, it is looking like this:

```
create table week_day (
daycode number (6) primary key,
day
```

It is obviously unfinished but, how can I set the local date to the `day` atribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really 100% sure I understand the question, but is this what you want?

```
create table week_day (
daycode number (6) primary key,
day date default sysdate
)
```

insert records as :

```
insert into week_day values( 1, sysdate);  etc.
```

Comment: I think that should do the trick